# How to determine if a user is subscribed on Apple Watch with no receipt on the device?

Tags: ios, apple-watch, storekit, watchos-6, universal-purchase

Apple's docs say

> Note: You don't need to create a universal purchase for a watchOS app with an iOS app because the app is already included in the same Xcode project as the iOS app. Learn how to add watchOS app information.

When you make a purchase, no receipt is found on the watch: https://twitter.com/AndresBoedo/status/1237816178057318401?s=20

So other than using `WCSession` to ask the iPhone if subscribed, how are we supposed to check on the watch?

Comment: Why not use `WCSession`?  Transfer the subscription state via `updateApplicatiinState`

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear @Paulw11 my last sentence I'm asking other than WCSession (which I'm doing now) how do we do it? It seems that in the era of stand alone watch applications we're going to get to a point soon (I hope as a watch developer) where users can purchase a watch without an iPhone (Android user etc.)...and so being so reliant on WCSession for such a crucial function doesn't seem very future proof.  I thought with In App Purchases on the watch now, this would have been addressed.

Comment: It has been addressed, but perhaps Apple has a bug. Did you test in app purchasing with a stand-alone watch app or a watch app with a companion app? The documentation says the receipt is available.

Comment: @Paulw11 tested on a watch app with a companion app.  Filed a Feedback that a receipt isn't found on the watch after making a purchase either on the iPhone or on the watch.

Comment: If the issue is important or urgent you might consider using a developer tech support incident on it; they may just confirm it is a bug, but it might be worth a try.